# C# Sluggish UI on Surface pro 3

Tags: c#

I'm coding an application on my surface pro 3. In the editor it looks just fine.. But when I run it, the application will look a bit sluggish and the folder browse dialog will not show anything inside it. So I can't really figure out why and how to sort that out. Never had anything like this happening before.

Picture:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgLsQ.png)

Comment: What's your RAM/CPU usage like while running?

Comment: What sort of framework are you using? Is it WPF? Etc.

Comment: @Steve Running about 80% ram while having 5+ tabs open in chrome. And around 20% cpu.

Comment: @Nobody It is Windows forms application.

Comment: Just a suggestion since it's such a simple app -- remake your project in WPF. Just copy and paste your code over. It should mostly work - some things are different, but WPF is microsofts new lovechild. It also automatically utilizes the GPU to render the app UI (Everything on it) It should speed your app up significantly.

Comment: @Nobody I will give it a try :). But it is still weird... Never had anything like this before...

Comment: Just a heads-up. WPF doesn't have a native folder browser dialog. However you can find nearly anything on NuGet (Right click the references list-item in the solution explorer). Ookii dialogs is a good one. http://www.ookii.org/

Comment: @Nobody OKay thanks! Will try this!

Comment: @StianTofte also try closing Chrome and reducing your other resource usage as much as possible, since the Surface Pro 3 is not exactly a hard core dev machine. Still, it shouldn't really matter for a simple app.